# Why unstyled input text has a border width of 2px?

Tags: css, browser, border, default, textinput

I have the following HTML markup which result to an input form element of type text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

In a decent browser it render like the following screen capture (in the right side the zoomed image):

[image: Sample]

Then, why when inspecting the `<input>` element the browser show a border width of **2px**? We can *visually* appreciate the input element has **1 pixel**. Even with jQuery when I do something like `jQuery('input').css('border-width')` it spit out **2px**.

Of course, this is happening *only with unstyled form input elements*.

I also created a JsFiddle demo:http://jsfiddle.net/HBDUZ/

Thanks!

Comment: Browser default stylesheet.

Comment: I guess that's just how your browser is set to render text fields with the default style. The text field says "1px" for me in Chrome on iOS for example. (iPhone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each browser has a built-in stylesheet (called a "user agent stylesheet"), which contains default styling for certain elements.

In this case (Chrome 25 beta-m, Windows), the style is:

```
border: 2px inset;
```

The result of `inset` is really visible in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5UQM/), with a contrasting background color.